# wait for few seconds for javascript to modify the page using curl call

Tags: php, curl, simple-html-dom

[image]

[image]

I am trying to crawl a page, but the problem is that a link is being generating after 5 seconds on the page. I want to read that link. I have tried two different methods

1. using curl call
2. simple_html_dom library [here](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

In Curl

```
$str = curl_exec($curl);
```

this function gives the response instantly but I want the response to wait for 5 sec or more and read the link which is being generated after 5 sec.

Or may be, I will temporarily render the page for 5 sec and then read the page. Is there any way that I can do this ?

Comment: So you want to load up your own page and then wait 5 seconds before javascript posts to your php controller with some kind of data?
I don't get your question.

Comment: Yes, javascript is making some change on the page after 5 sec and I want to read that change.

Comment: PHP can"t execute JS scripts, so you can only download the static page... Your best hope is to figure out how the script is generating that link and try to reproduce it... Start by Checking the network tab of your navigator's developper tool `ctrl+shift+i` to see what's being exchanged between your navigator and the server

Comment: I know that, but my requirement is only to read the page after few sec. All I am looking for some theory or technique to render the page somewhere using curl(or some other library) and wait for some time and get the output/changes. And you are suggesting that its not possible!

Comment: you can easily do this using vb .net and the WebBrowser control. I can't think how you can do this in php (you could with iframes if both sites were in the same domain -but obviously this is not the case)

Comment: yes, see I am on the server end and I am not expecting any web brwowser here. so may be there could be some library which can render the page in some sort of sandbox (which is very hard to find)  type of application,but like the curl library which fetch the data from the url, may be some additional functionality/plugin could be added to render and wait in curl.

Comment: Just parse the JS code and extract the redirecting URL!